# Find a portion of string in a string and change it with PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

i have this string:

```
 $string= " 22 December-28 December 2015";
```

exist a method in PHP with i can find the word "December" inside $string and changes it with another word ?

i would like a new:

```
 $string= " 22 Dicembre-28 Dicembre 2015";
```

Comment: This method is `str_replace`.

Comment: str_ireplace — Case-insensitive version of str_replace().

Answer (score 4):

You could use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)() function.

Something like this:

```
$string= " 22 December-28 December 2015";
$string = str_replace('December', 'Dicembre', $string);
```